# How to connect CellConst flange Outflow to Cell1Dim flange Inflow

Tags: modelica, dymola

I am curently working on hydraulics task using Thermocycle library. 
Is there a way to connect the `Outflow` flange of a `CellConst` module to the `Inflow` flange of a `Cell1Dim` module and vice versa?

I do not want any calculation to be done.
I just want to intersect a `CellConst` block between two `Cell1Dim` blocks.
This cannot be achieved by their default flanges.

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: If you do not receive answers here, you might as well try the ThermoCycle issue tracker: https://github.com/thermocycle/Thermocycle-library/issues